# Update when joining multiple tables failed

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to update two tables using a join, and my Codeigniter model code is here:

```
$patient_secondary = array(
    'vpd.patient_id'=>$data['patient_id'],
    'mpd.patient_id'=>$data['patient_id'],
    'vpd.reason'=> 'Death/Expiry',
    'vpd.status_' => 0,
    'mpd.status_' => 0,
);
$this->db->set($patient_secondary);
$this->db->where('`vpd`.`patient_id`', $data['patient_id']);
$this->db->where('`mpd`.`patient_id`', $data['patient_id']);
$this->db->update('volga_primary_patient_details  AS vpd JOIN master_patient_details AS mpd ON vpd.patiend_id = mpd.patient_id');
```

But I get the following error:

```
A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '.`patiend_id = mpd`.`patient_id` SET `vpd`.`patient_id` = '22', `mpd`.`patient_i' at line 1

UPDATE `volga_primary_patient_details AS vpd JOIN master_patient_details` AS `mpd ON vpd`.`patiend_id = mpd`.`patient_id` SET `vpd`.`patient_id` = '22', `mpd`.`patient_id` = '22', `vpd`.`reason` = 'Death/Expiry', `vpd`.`status_` = 0, `mpd`.`status_` = 0 WHERE `vpd`.`patient_id` = '22' AND `mpd`.`patient_id` = '22'


Line Number: 691
```

Comment: use `$this->db->join()` vs passing it as part of the update string as the update method is reading that entire string as if its the table name only.

Comment: When i use $this->db->join(), i get following error

Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'mpd.patient_id' in 'where clause'

UPDATE `volga_primary_patient_details` AS `vpd` SET `vpd`.`patient_id` = '22', `mpd`.`patient_id` = '22', `vpd`.`reason` = 'Death/Expiry', `vpd`.`status_` = 0, `mpd`.`status_` = 0 WHERE `vpd`.`patient_id` = '22' AND `mpd`.`patient_id` = '22'

Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/masterhetero/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691

Comment: Did you have an alias as `mpd`?  Does that table have the column `patient_id`?

Comment: yes... master_patient_details` AS `mpd and it has patient_id has column name

Answer (score 0):

Syntax error... look closely at

```
... ON vpd`.`patiend_id = mpd`.`patient_id` SET ...
```

- missing backtick before vpd
- missing backtick after patient_id
- missing backtick before mpd

Alas, I don't know how CodeIgniter creates the query.. your code looks ok to me (backticks present there)

Comment: UPDATE `volga_primary_patient_details` as `vpd` JOIN `master_patient_details` as `mpd` ON `vpd`.`patient_id` = `mpd`.`patient_id` SET `vpd`.`patient_id` = '22', `vpd`.`status_` = 0, `mpd`.`patient_id` = '22', `mpd`.`status_` = 0 WHERE `vpd`.`patient_id` = '22' AND `mpd`.`patient_id` = '22'

yes i have corrected the code and try to executed in myphpadmin, it works fine. but when coming to codeignitor, it creates the query, but with error..